# OpenCV: How to pass a multi-channel matrix as a function argument?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a function with this signature: `process(Mat_<float>&)`. I can pass a single channel matrix to it like this:

```
Mat img = cv::imread(inPath, 0);
Mat_<float> imgReal;
img.convertTo(imgReal, CV_32F, 1.0/255.0);
process(imgReal);
```

No complaints. But how can I pass a matrix of type `CV_32FC2` with two channels? The matrix is created like this:

```
Mat img = cv::imread(inPath, 0);
Mat_<float> imgReal;
img.convertTo(imgReal, CV_32F, 1.0/255.0);
Mat imgImag = Mat(imgReal.rows, imgReal.cols, CV_32F, float(0));
vector<Mat> channels;
channels.push_back(imgReal);
channels.push_back(imgImag);
Mat imgComplex = Mat(imgReal.rows, imgReal.cols, CV_32FC2);
merge(channels,imgComplex);
process(imgComplex);
```

Now when I call `process(imgComplex)`, the compiler throws `main.cpp:140:74: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘cv::Mat_<float>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘cv::Mat_<float>’`

What exactly is the cause of that?

Comment: `imgComplex` is not an rvalue. Do you really call it like `process(imgComplex)` to get exactly that error?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was wondering too. It works when I change the function to `process(const Mat&)`.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. To be honest I cannot believe that you get that error from that code

Comment: is maybe `Mat` not the same type as `Mat_<float>`, but there exist a conversion? That could also explain the error, sorry I am not familiar with opencv

Comment: `cv::Mat_<cv::Vec2f>` .. or simply `cv::Mat2f`. See [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html).

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, both are float matrices but in the lower example, it has two channels.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks! However now the compiler throws `main.cpp:140:74: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘cv::Mat2f& {aka cv::Mat_<cv::Vec<float, 2> >&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘cv::Mat2f {aka cv::Mat_<cv::Vec<float, 2> >}’` `/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:1398:1: note:   after user-defined conversion: cv::Mat_<_Tp>::Mat_(const cv::Mat&) [with _Tp = cv::Vec<float, 2>]
 Mat_<_Tp>::Mat_(const Mat& m)` `note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void process(cv::Mat2f&)’`

Comment: That's due to the non-const reference. When you pass a `Mat` instead of `Mat2f`, a temporary `Mat2f` is created -- trying to take a non-const reference of this is a no-no. | What exactly does your `process` function do with that `Mat`? There's a good chance you don't really need the reference.

Comment: Aah yeah of course, I changed the function signature to `Mat2f` but not the declaration of `imgComplex`. I did and now it works as intended, thanks! In `process` actually the first action is to `clone()` the input matrix because it runs in multiple threads. Is it better to pass a `const` matrix then in this case?, Sorry, I recently switched from Python... :) Feel free to type an answer about the typing btw and I'll accept it!

Comment: if you need to make a copy anyhow then pass by value

Comment: had to make a mini edit to be able to revert my downvote (which was due to a misunderstanding ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is similar to this:

```
struct asdf {
    asdf(int x){} // converting constructor
};
process(asdf& x) {}
```

Given this, the following is allowed

```
asdf x = 3;   // calls converting constructor
process(x);   // pass lvalue
```

but what is not allowed is this:

```
int x = 3;
process(x);   // attempts to call converting constructor 
              // and pass the result (rvalue!) to process
```

Because the rvalue resulting from the conversion is not allowed to bind to a non-const reference. As a fix, either change the signature of process (would be `process(int&)` for this example) or do the conversion and calling the funtion in two steps (analog to the first snippet).

Comment: As pointed out by Dan Masek, the correct type here would be `cv::Mat_<cv::Vec2f>` or `cv::Mat2f`.